# Site-wide nav links responding on one page but not another?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, materialize

i'm building a site on rails and have implemented a site-wide navbar to show up on all pages. The problem is it shows up on both pages however the links and hover states are clickable only on one page? I can't figure out what has gone wrong as i'm rendering the same _navigation.html.erb and nav.scss files?

---

_navigation.html.erb

```
<nav>
  <div class="container nav-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" id="brand-logo" class="col l2"><img src="<%= asset_path('social-playground-logo.png')%>"></a>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" class=" col l10 right hide-on-med-and-down nav-desktop">
            <li><a id="link-home" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="link-toys" href="">Toys</a></li>
            <li><a id="link-pastevents" href="">Past Events</a></li>
            <li><a id="link-contacts" href="">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a id="link-partners" href="">Partners</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

gifpage.html.erb navbar and hero-image extract(that is working normally)

```
<div class="hero-image-container group">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <img id="gif-foreground-hero" src="<%= asset_path( 'GIF Foreground FInal.png') %>" class="responsive-img">
```

selfies.html.erb navbar and hero-image extract(that is not working normally)

```
<div class="selfies-hero-image-container group">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <img id="selfie-foreground-hero" src="<%= asset_path( 'Selfie-hero-foreground.png') %>" class="responsive-img">
```

_nav.scss for both

```
nav {
    height: 112px;
    line-height: 23px;
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);

    .nav-container {
        width: 100%;

        #brand-logo {
            transform: scale(0.8);
            margin-top: 7px;
            margin-left: 4%;
        }

        #nav-mobile {
            margin-right: 0%;
            margin-left: 0%;
            width: 79.33333%;
        }

        ul li {
            margin-top: 27px;
            margin-left: 29px;

            a {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 14px 25px;
                display: inline-block;

                &:hover {
                    border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### }

The border appears on :hover for the gif page but not selfies.

Thanks guys[image: Both hero images to appear beneath a 0.5 opacity navbar]

[image: The blue kero image is the page not working]

Both hero images appear through the navbar which has 0.5 opacity.

Thanks

---

EDIT

printout from the terminal

```
Started GET "/gifpage" for 59.167.19.225 at 2015-10-21 05:30:23 +0000
Cannot render console from 59.167.19.225! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PagesController#gifpage as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered pages/gifpage.html.erb within layouts/application (62.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 445ms (Views: 444.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

with,

```
Started GET "/assets/_nav-87ab5873b40bcbbebe26b4faa985fc95.css?body=1"
```

as the _nav.scss file being rendered for the page that's working,
and,

```
Started GET "/" for 59.167.19.225 at 2015-10-21 05:34:25 +0000
Cannot render console from 59.167.19.225! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PagesController#selfies as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered pages/selfies.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 410ms (Views: 408.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

with,

```
Started GET "/assets/_nav-87ab5873b40bcbbebe26b4faa985fc95.css?body=1"
```

being rendered for the page not working.

I also compared both css and structure side-by-side in chrome inspect element and both were exactly the same. Still no idea!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source, and see if the same .css file is rendered by the asset pipeline; maybe different controllers have different css files. Alternatively inspect element will show you what css is loaded for each. Maybe you're also hitting the css ordering of LVHA (link/visited/hover/active).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!..still no luck though. See the edits to the question for the results. This is really bugging me! Any other ideas? Also, both are within the same pages_controller and under the same pages view. 'pages#gifpage' and 'pages#selfies'

Comment: look at your inspect element (should be the first step always!) try playing with the class in there to see if you can get it to activate.

Comment: inspect element will show you which css is applied and which file it came from, which may help!

Comment: Thanks court3nay for you reply but I've tried to compare them both side-by-side but they are structured the exact same way and have the same css?!..

Comment: ok, i'm not saying to inspect the html, I'm saying to look at the css that it is applying. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics?hl=en, on the right hand column. If it has the same, then it's probably something dumb, like try restarting your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Thankyou for your answers. Today i solved the problem. The hero image was actually sitting over the nav list items so completely rendering the hover action useless(i.e the browser read it as me hovering over the image and not the navbar). Changing the image's z-index to 1 and the navbar's z-index to 2 fixed the issue. The browser now reads it as me hovering over the navbar, with the image positioned a layer behind it. After trying everything I decided to just start from scratch and build the page again, except this time, for whatever reason, I made the overlaying image a tad smaller. This caused the hover action to appear only on the very outside of the navbar but not the rest, leading me to solving the problem.

Thanks again,
Justin